# Select dependientes PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Saludos, estoy creando una aplicación web para dar de alta vacantes de empleo utilizando PHP, MySQL y un poco de Javascript. 
Mi problema es que quiero filtrar por nivel educativo para que no aparezcan todos los registros. Pensaba usar un switch dentro de PHP pero parece que no funciona. Como dato, el primer select no se necesita sacar de Base de datos, ya que sólo necesito una clave incluida en el value de "option" con la cual, hago el LIKE en la consulta. 
Si tienen una solución usando esas tres herramientas (quiero evitar Ajax y jQuery porque no los domino mucho y estoy a contratiempo con esta solución), les agradecería de antemano. Adjunto el código:

```
<div content>
    <table background="../img/201.png" cellspacing="21" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>

                <br /> 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <form action="getQna.php" method="post">
        <tr>
            <td>
                Seleccionar el nivel educativo:
                <br />
                <select name="nivelE" id="nivelE" onchange="nivelEduc()">
                    <option value="ShowAll" selected="selected">Seleccione nivel:</option>
                    <option value="24DDI">Educaci&oacute;n Inicial</option>
                    <option value="24DJN">Preescolar</option>
                    <option value="24DPR">Primaria</option>
                    <option value="24DST">Secundarias T&eacute;cnicas</option>

                </select>
                <br />
                <br />
                Seleccionar la plaza vacante:
                <br />
                <select name="plazaS" id="plazaS" onchange="alerta()">
                    <option value="showAll" selected="selected">Seleccione:</option>
     <?php
    require_once 'config.php';


    $stmt = $dbcon->prepare('SELECT * FROM analitico where estatus="V"');
    $stmt->execute();

    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        extract($row);
        ?>
        <option value="<?php $concat= $plaza . " " . $ct; echo $concat; ?>"><?php echo $plaza; ?></option> 
        <?php
    }
    ?>              
            </select>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Clave de Centro de Trabajo:</label>
                <br />
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <input type="hidden" id="plaza" name="plaza"/> <!--Aquí se desconcatena-->
                        <input type="text"  id="ct" name="ct" readonly="readonly"/>
                        <input type="hidden" id="nivel" name="nivel"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <td align="justify">
    <!--Aquí se va a poner a elegir lo de la vacancia temporal o permanente--->
        Ingrese el inicio de la vacancia:
        <br />

            <input type="text" name="qna_ini" id="qna_ini" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" maxlength="6" autocomplete="off"/>
    </td >
    <td align="justify">
        Ingrese el fin de la vacancia:
        <br />
            <input type="text" name="qna_fin" id="qna_fin" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" maxlength="6" autocomplete="off" />

    </td>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <input type="submit" />
        </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
function alerta()
{   
     var x = document.getElementById("plazaS").value,
    separador = " ", // un espacio en blanco
    arregloDeSubCadenas = x.split(separador);
    console.log(arregloDeSubCadenas);
    document.getElementById("ct").value = arregloDeSubCadenas[1];
    document.getElementById("plaza").value = arregloDeSubCadenas[0];
}

function nivelEduc()
{
    var nivel=document.getElementById("nivelE").value;
    console.log(nivel);
    document.getElementById("nivel").value=nivel;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hay una biblioteca de JQuery es muy fácil de implementar, evitará que uses AJAX, solo tienes que exportarla y agregara tus filtros se llama [zelect](https://github.com/mtkopone/zelect).

Básicamente solo necesitaras estas lineas:

```
<select id="async-backed-zelect"></select>
$('#async-backed-zelect').zelect({ placeholder:'Plz select..' });
```

Considero que te seria muy útil si lo que quieres es filtrar tu **select** y minimizar tiempos de desarrollo.
Se que ocupa JQuery pero es un coste por un desarrollo más rápido, y menos lineas de código.

Comment: Lo que deseo hacer es que el usuario seleccione primero el nivel y que con base al nivel, filtre los que empiecen con determinada clave (Por ejemplo, si eligió Preescolar, que sólo muestre los que empiezan con 24DJN, si es primaria, con 24DPR) lo cual sé que con MySQL es con el Like, pero no sé cómo pasar de PHP o de HTML a ese LIKE.

Comment: En ese sentido para recargar un elemento dentro de una pagina necesariamente necesitas AJAX(para eso fue diseñado), si no quisieras usar, has el switch pero desde javascript ya que el servidor solo compila el código en PHP una vez y lo envía al cliente, donde solo podrás ocupar JS.

Comment: Entonces probaré suerte con AJAX, muchas gracias